# Where can I find the verdict of Harvey Weinstein's trial?

Tags: criminal-law

I want to find raw information about Harvey Weinstein's trial.
Verdict, protocol, court documents, etc.

Preferably from an official government source.

Help or links appreciated

Comment: It's doubtful that these are available yet, you may have to file a FOIA request directly with the court involved to get those documents, and they may be sealed for some time.

Answer (score 1):

You could likely find the jury instructions through New York court systems (I believe the state with legal jurisdiction) if it is online, but there is a likely timeliness issue as it's less than 24 hours old at time of asking and writing this answer.  Either rate, when posted, all documents generated by the proceedings will be found through the NY court website, NYCourts.gov Can't get any more official government source than that.

Though it's been my experience that different states have different navigation systems of various civil and criminal courts that can be rather easy to use to "I never found the engine" but New York's system looks like it should be easy to search from a quick glance.

Access should be free, as it is a matter of public record, unless you want physical copies, which may have some cost of buisnesses to send.  Additionally, news articles will often link to digital documents of court filings in their coverage.

For a jury trial, don't expect much reading as the document will only contain the decision (guilty or not guilty) but not how or why they agree on that issue.  Great pain is taken to isolate juries in major cases like this so they're only discussing facts of the case with each other.  The Jury Instructions are much more interesting as they are the questions the jury needs to ask if the facts support a guilty verdict as are the judge's ruling during sentancing (where the judge gets to add his opinion on the matter.  As of time of writing, this has not yet happened).